# Автор добился(,) чего хотел

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

`Автор добился(,) чего хотел.`

Comment: Я думаю, что это местоименно-определительное придаточное, местоименная пара ТОГО—ЧЕГО (союзное слово). Указательное слово в общем случае обязательно, но в разговорном стиле опускается. Здесь нет изъяснительной части. А вы как ДУМАЕТЕ? Сравнить: Добился (чего?), чтобы курева прислали. Здесь есть изъяснительное содержание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указательного слова "того" в предложении нет, но запятая перед придаточным изъяснительным (дополнительным) все равно ставится:

*Автор добился* (чего?)*, чего хотел.*

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:
*— Вот что значит твердый характер. **Добился, чего хотел!** И курево прислали, и бадейку винца раздобыл...* (Дмитрий Каралис. Летающий водопроводчик);
*— **Добилась, чего хотела**?* (Андрей Геласимов. Дом на Озерной);
*— Калугина отвернулась и говорила, глядя в окно: — Она потребует от вас много сил. **Вы же добились, чего хотели*** (Эльдар Рязанов, Эмиль Брагинский. Служебный роман).

[Придаточные дополнительные (изъяснительные)](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/738-222_pridatochnye_dopolnitelnye_izyasnitelnye.html)

Comment: Я думаю, что это местоименно-определительное придаточное, местоименная пара ТОГО—ЧЕГО (союзное слово). Указательное слово в общем случае обязательно, но в разговорном стиле опускается. Здесь нет изъяснительной части. А вы как ДУМАЕТЕ? Сравнить: Добился (чего?), чтобы курева прислали. Здесь есть изъяснительное содержание.