# "Автор добился, чего хотел". Какой вид придаточного? Изъяснительное или местоименно-определительное?

Tags: грамматика, тип-придаточных

Предложение из **[вопроса](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476500/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB),** который обсуждался на форуме:

*Автор добился(,) **чего хотел.***

Я думаю, что это придаточное **местоименно-определительное** (местоимение в роли дополнения),  но в ответе оно было названо **дополнительным (изъяснительным).**

**Аргументы такие:**

Местоименная пара ***ТОГО — ЧЕГО*** (указ. слово — союзное слово). Указательное слово в общем случае **обязательно**, но в разговорном стиле **опускается**. Здесь **нет изъяснительной части**.  Сравнить: *Добился (чего?), **чтобы** курева прислали.* Здесь есть **изъяснительное** содержание.

**У Кустовой (тема обозначена как трудные случаи разбора):**

*Он знает **то, чего** никто не знает.* Придаточное **не является** изъяснительным, так как в нем не передается содержание знания, а указывается **характеристика.** Придаточное относится к местоимению. Указ. слово в общем случае обязательно.

**Сравнить:** *Он узнал **о том, что** произошло*. Изъяснительное придаточное, передается **содержание знания.** Указ. слово не является обязательным, придаточное относится к глаголу.

Разница **существенная.**

```
 Русский язык — это сайт вопросов и ответов для 
 лингвистов и энтузиастов русского языка.
```

**Пожалуйста, обозначьте свое мнение.**  Это же грамматика! **Трудный случай разбора!** Самая подходящая **для форума тема.** Я задавала вопрос **в комментариях,** но никто не ответил.

Comment: Согласен с вами. Но с другой стороны, по традиционной классификации это предложение можно отнести к придаточному дополнительному. https://studfile.net/preview/7403017/page:10/

Comment: Серж, можно назвать дополнительными, но уж никак не изъяснительными. (Я бы их лучше называла объектными, да и то это школьные  названия.) Местоимение-коррелят  в главном предложении может быть подлежащим, сказуемым, дополнением. Здесь важна функция указ.  слова: его можно опустить только в разговорном стиле. Это надо было отметить в ответе.  Да и тема вопроса, как я думаю,  была другая. Надо было сравнить с устойчивыми сочетаниями вида «Он делает что хочет».